# Android: NullPointerException when retrieving info from sql database

Tags: android

I have a problem that i'm unable to solve for a couple of days now.
I've created methods to write and retrieve data to and from the db, but theres a problem that I can't find. 
Here is the code:

```
    public void writeEntry(String name, long period, long frequency, long recievingTime, String stats){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_PERIOD, period);
        cv.put(KEY_FREQUENCY, frequency);
        cv.put(KEY_RECIEVINGTIME, recievingTime);
        cv.put(KEY_STATS, stats);
        myDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public Cursor query(String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor c = myDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, null, null);
        return c;
    }
```

Here is the method to write data to the db:

```
 public void save(){
    sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SPNAME, 0);
    Log.v(" info", sharedPrefs.getAll().toString());
    Database database = new Database(context);
    database.open();
    database.writeEntry(
            sharedPrefs.getString(NAME, "No data was found"), 
            sharedPrefs.getLong(PERIOD, 0),
            sharedPrefs.getLong(FREQUENCY, 0), 
            sharedPrefs.getLong(RECIEVINGTIME, 0), 
            sharedPrefs.getString(STATS, "No data was found")
            );
    database.close();
}
```

And here is how I retrieve it:

```
 public List<String> getReportInfo(String rowId){
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    database = new Database(context);
    database.open();
    cursor = database.query(new String[]{
            Database.KEY_NAME,
            Database.KEY_PERIOD,
            Database.KEY_FREQUENCY,
            Database.KEY_RECIEVINGTIME,
            Database.KEY_STATS},
            Database.KEY_ROWID +" = "+rowId, null, null);
    for(cursor.moveToFirst(); cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
        result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getPosition()));
    }
    cursor.close(); 
    database.close();   
    return result;
}
```

Later on, I use data from db in BaseAdapter in getView method to populate the ListView like this:

```
  public class MyArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter{  

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    TextView tvMyReportsPeriod, tvMyReportsFrequency, tvMyReportsReceivingTime, tvMyReportTitle;
    LinearLayout llMyReportsStats;
    Database database;
    Report report;
    Cursor cursor;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Activity a) {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        activity = a;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        report = new Report(activity);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int count = 2;
        try{
        cursor = database.query(new String[]{Database.KEY_NAME}, null, null, null);
        count= cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        }catch(Exception e){}
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<String> list = report.getReportInfo(String.valueOf(position));
        return list;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_reports_view_holder, null, false);

            tvMyReportsPeriod = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMyReportsPeriod);
            tvMyReportsFrequency = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMyReportsFrequency);
            tvMyReportsReceivingTime = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMyReportsReceivingTime);
            tvMyReportTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMyReportTitle);
            llMyReportsStats = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.llMyReportsStats);

                List<String> data = report.getReportInfo(String.valueOf(position));
                if(data!=null){
                    tvMyReportTitle.setText(data.get(0));
                    tvMyReportsPeriod.setText(report.convertMillis(Long.parseLong(data.get(1))));
                    tvMyReportsFrequency.setText(report.convertMillis(Long.parseLong(data.get(2))));
                    tvMyReportsReceivingTime.setText(report.convertMillis(Long.parseLong(data.get(3))));
                    String[] stats = data.get(4).toString().split(" ");             
                    for(int x=0; x<stats.length; x++){
                        TextView textView = new TextView(activity);
                        for(Constants dc: Constants.values()){
                            if(dc.getId()==Integer.parseInt(stats[x])){
                                textView.setText(dc.getText());
                            }
                        }
                        llMyReportsStats.addView(textView); 
                    }
                }else{System.out.println("ERROR: data=null");}
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

I expect to get one row from db at a time for each ListView item, but instead I get this logcat:

```
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at com.dailyreports.ainius.Report.getReportInfo(Report.java:107)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at com.dailyreports.ainius.MyReports$MyArrayAdapter.getView(MyReports.java:88)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:841)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1861)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3729)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
09-27 11:03:03.173: E/AndroidRuntime(25768):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Don't know where's the problem. Please help.

Comment: can you post complete stack trace?

Comment: Post your `BaseAdapter` also with your `LogCat`

Comment: Sory, i get CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException, i just edited my post

Comment: this is the cause `result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getPosition()));`, you should `getString(columnIndex)` not current position of your cursor.

Comment: while(moveToNext()) does the same as your for loop in a more concise fashion

Comment: please format your stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit : Seems like what you want is retrieving a single row from your DB.

You should use `MyObject` instead of `List<String>` to achieve what you want.

Here is an example of `MyObject`, see [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)

```
public class MyObject {
    String name = "", stats = "";
    Long period = 0, frequency = 0, receivingtime = 0;

    // empty constructor
    public MyObject() {
    }

    // simple getter method
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // simple setter method
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    ...
    // You may want to override toString() method when implementing searching or using ArrayAdapter
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + stats;
    }
}
```

Change your `getReportInfo` to :

```
public MyObject getReportInfo(String rowId){
    MyObject result = new MyObject();
    database = new Database(context);
    database.open();
    cursor = database.query(new String[]{
            Database.KEY_NAME,
            Database.KEY_PERIOD,
            Database.KEY_FREQUENCY,
            Database.KEY_RECIEVINGTIME,
            Database.KEY_STATS},
            Database.KEY_ROWID +" = "+rowId, null, null);
    // this will prevent CursorIndexOutofBoundsException
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        result.setName(cursor.getString(0));
        result.setPeriod(cursor.getLong(1));
        result.setFrequency(cursor.getLong(2));
        result.setReceivingTime(cursor.getLong(3));
        result.setStats(cursor.getString(4));
    }
    cursor.close(); 
    database.close();   
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check that `cursor.moveToFirst()` returned true.

If the query you are doing does not have any result, you will get that `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception...

Also, as Aprian noted. `cursor.getString` takes the column index as argument, not the position of the cursor.

Replace `result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getPosition()));` with `result.add(cursor.getString(Database.KEY_STATS));`

Answer (score 0):

This `cursor.getString(cursor.getPosition())` does not cause the error you posted, but will cause other errors later. The parameter expected, if you read the documentation, is the column index, not the row index.

The error you are observing is probably caused by the fact that moveToFirst returns False but you are not testing it. You database is empty.

## edit

after reading it again, your for loop (while very nice looking) is completly off. You test isAfterLast as a loop condition, while at best it should be an **exit** condition. You don't check the result of move to first. You don't check the result of moveToNext.

Replace your for loop with

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems here too:

```
result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getPosition()));
```

Because if the number of fetched records are more than the number of columns requested in the query, it will throw error. This is not the way you should read values out from cursor, in fact you should identify which columns value it should read. For example:

```
result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.KEY_NAME)));
```

or perhaps with fixed index value, for example:

```
result.add(cursor.getString(0));
```